# Apollo Client V2 fetches data the wrong order

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authorization, graphql, apollo

I am building an application which uses authorization with Json Web Tokens. I'm building this application with Node.js, GraphQL and Apollo client V2 (and some other stuff, but those aren't related here). I have created a `login` resolver and a `currentUser` resolver that let me get the current user via a JWT. I later use that token and send it in my authorization headers and the results looks something like:

[image]
So that part is done! But here's what I'm having trouble with.

### Me trying to explain the situation

I'm using React for the frontend part of this project with the Apollo Client V2. And when I do the login mutation I do it like this. With formik I've created my `onSubmit`:

```
const response = await mutate({
  variables: {
    email: values.email,
    password: values.password,
  },
})
const token = response.data.login.jwt
localStorage.setItem('token', token)

history.push('/') // Navigating to the home page
```

And this is what I want back with the login mutation (just the token):

```
export const loginMutation = gql`
  mutation($email: String!, $password: String!) {
    login(email: $email, password: $password) {
      jwt
    }
  }
`
```

To get the `currentUser`'s data I've put my `currentUser query` in my root router file. **Please apologize me for naming the component PrivateRoute. I haven't renamed it yet because I can't find a proper name for it. I'm sorry.** So in `/src/router/index.js` I have this:

```
// First the actual query
const meQuery = gql`
{
  currentUser {
    id
    username
    email
  }
}
`

...

// A component that passess the currentUser as a prop, otherwise it will be null
const PRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        return (
          <Component
            {...props}
            currentUser={
              rest.meQuery.currentUser ? rest.meQuery.currentUser : null
            }
          />
        )
      }}
    />
  )
}

// Another component that uses the meQuery so I later can access it if I use the PrivateRoute component.
const PrivateRoute = graphql(meQuery, { name: 'meQuery' })(PRoute)

// Using the PrivateRoute. And in my Home component I can later grap the currentUser via propsb
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
...
```

In the `Home` component I grab the prop:

```
const { data: { loading, error, getAllPosts = [], currentUser } } = this.props
```

I pass it down to my `Navbar` component:

```
<Navbar currentUser={this.props.currentUser} />
```

And in the `Navbar` component I take the username if it exists:

```
const { username } = this.props.currentUser || {}
```

And then I render it.

### This is what I'm having troubles with

My application is currently trying to get the `currentUser` when I get to the `/login` route. And after I've successfully loged in I get back the token, but the `currentUser query` is not being fetched again. Thefore I have to refresh my page to get the current user and all of it's values.

I have also created a little video that demonstrates what my problem is. I believe  it will show you more clearly the problem than me trying to type it.

Here's the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyI_itthtaE

I also want to thank you for reading my post and that you hopefully are going to help me. I have no idea why this is happening to me and I just can't seem to solve it. I've tried to write this question as best as I can, so sorry if it was confusing to read.

Thanks

Comment: First fetching token does not re-fetch query, you should be doing it or something to re-fetch.
Second, there is bug that after your query produce error, it does not subscribe to store. That means when you refetch it from somewhere, your grahql HoC will not update.
That is why current solution would be to use `skip:` to not even try to fetch user till token was fetched. And after you fetch token you change some state or prop passed to graphql HoC so it will try to fetch the user first time.

Comment: Thanks for replying @RobertSimon! I thought that after I've added my token to my localstorage and then navigate to `/` route it will then fetch the currentUser with the token. How did you notice that it doesn't subscribe to the store? Also, I noticed that you are mister shockitv on Slack. Would you mind chatting there? I understand if you don't have time/ don't want to! 

Thanks for replying again.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be able to solve this issue by setting the query's **FetchPolicy** to **"cache-and-network"**. You can read about fetch policies [here: "GraphQL query options.fetchPolicy"](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#graphql-config-options-fetchPolicy)

in your specific case I think you can update this line

```
const PrivateRoute = graphql(meQuery, { name: 'meQuery' })(PRoute)
```

to this:

```
const PrivateRoute = graphql(meQuery, { name: 'meQuery', options: {fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'} })(PRoute)
```

### Explanation

As stated in the documentation, the default policy is *cache-first*.

1. *currentUser* is queried the first time and it updates the cache.
2. You execute the login mutation, the **cache is not updated** without
   you updating it (read about it [here: "Updating the cache    after a
   mutation"](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/mutations.html#store-updates)).
3. *currentUser* query is executed again but due to the default *cache-first* policy the outdated result will be retrieved only from the cache.

From the [official documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#graphql-config-options-fetchPolicy):

> **cache-first**: This is the default value where we always try reading
>   data from your cache first. If all the data needed to fulfill your
>   query is in the cache then that data will be returned. Apollo will
>   only fetch from the network if a cached result is not available. This
>   fetch policy aims to minimize the number of network requests sent when
>   rendering your component.
>
> **cache-and-network**: This fetch policy will have Apollo first trying to read data from your cache. If all the data needed to fulfill your
>   query is in the cache then that data will be returned. However,
>   regardless of whether or not the full data is in your cache this
>   fetchPolicy will always execute query with the network interface
>   unlike cache-first which will only execute your query if the query
>   data is not in your cache. This fetch policy optimizes for users
>   getting a quick response while also trying to keep cached data
>   consistent with your server data at the cost of extra network
>   requests.

in addition to these two there are two more policies: 'network-only' and 'cache-only' here's the [link to the documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#graphql-config-options-fetchPolicy)

Comment: Hello! Thanks for you detailed explanation. I tried your solution, but unfortunately it didn't do the trick. I'm still trying to make this work. Seems like I'll never solve this

Answer (score 1):

for me it worked when I refetched the currentUser query in my login mutation. I added my code below. Maybe it helps:

```
onSubmit(event) {
event.preventDefault();

const { email, password } = this.state;

this.props
  .mutate({
    variables: { email, password },
    update: (proxy, { data }) => {
      // Get Token from response and set it to the localStorage
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.login.jwt);
    },
    refetchQueries: [{ query: currentUser }]
  })
  .catch((res) => {
    const errors = res.graphQLErrors.map(error => error.message);
    this.setState({ errors });
  });
}
```